# KAFKA connector Apply Tansform.filter.Value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have create a connector to azureEventhub , it works fine to pull the data into the topic ,
My use case is to filter the messages that I m pullling basing on the message type .
Example :

```
  {
    "messageType": "Transformed",
    "timeStamp": 1652113146105,
    "payload": {
      "externalId": "24323",
      "equipmentType": "TemperatureSensor",
      "measureType": "Temperature",
      "normalizedData": {
        "equipmentData": [
          {
            "key": "ReadingValue",
            "value": 23,
            "valueType": "number",
            "measurementUnit": "celsius",
            "measurementDateTime": "2022-05-09T16:18:34.0000000Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      "dataProviderName": "LineMetrics"
    },
  },
```

---

```
 {
    "messageType": "IntegratorGenericDataStream",
    "timeStamp": 1652113146103,
    "payload": {
      "dataSource": {
        "type": "sensor",
      },
      "dataPoints": [
        {
          "type": "Motion",
          "value": 0,
          "valueType": "number",
          "dateTime": "2022-05-09T16:18:37.0000000Z",
          "unit": "count"
        }
      ],
      "dataProvider": {
        "id": "ba84cbdb-cbf8-4d4f-9a55-93b43f671b5a",
        "name": "LineMetrics",
        "displayName": "Line Metrics"
      }
    },
  }
```

**I wanted to apply a filter on a value like shown in the pic:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu1XO.png)

the error that appears to me :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7VS7.png)

Comment: Your data is just JSON? Without a schema? As the error says, a Struct is required, which means you'd need to use a different Converter than the JSON one

Comment: @OneCricketeer , I added a schema JSON_SR to my topic , but still same error

Comment: You mean you modified the connector converter? Simply adding a schema to the registry won't do anything unless you configure clients to use it. And it won't fix existing data in the topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer I applied        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.JsonConverter" to my connector and still nothing chmaged

Comment: Neither of those converters use the schema registry. `JSON_SR` needs to use a class like `io.confluent...JSONSchemaConverter`... But, you have no schema within your JSON. You can read more about how Connect uses Schemas on this [blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained). Without a Struct/Schema (this is a Connect concept, not related to the Schema _Registry_), then your data is just a plain string and `@.messageType` cannot be interpreted